# How do find out WHY webpack has put modules inside a specific module

Tags: webpack, optimization, bundle, code-splitting

I've got a large codebase for a fairly complicated site. We let webpack (4.33.+) do the splitting for us. After all it's a clever thing. This is what we use (we are OK with the vendor bundle)

```
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      name: false,
      cacheGroups: {
        commons: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendor',
          chunks: 'initial',
        },
      },
    },
    runtimeChunk: 'single',
  },
```

Running the webpack analyzer:

```
plugins: [new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({ analyzerMode: 'static' })],
```

We get to see what files are included where. For most of the time Webpack happily detects our 'Pages' (it's an SPA so essentially JS ;)) But for one of our bigger 'Pages' it simply adds it to our 'App' bundle.

We tried various ways (online visualizers etc but our codebase is so big they struggle) to see why had Webpack decided it should be inside that bundle and not like most of our others.

WE understand it is looking at a dependency graph but i cannot see how it's thinking they should be 'together'. Its not our entry point.

As an example we also told Webpack to directly create a bundle for that particular set of files but then it simply load 2 js each time so obviously it thinks (and i presume correct :)) they are linked *somehow*

My question: what is the technical process of finding out how to get to the dependency issue? Clicking on the visualizer does not tell us 'why'

For example is there a tool that say something like:

File X is included in Bundle A (app -> entrypoint) because:

- Inside A is a reference to something in File X (via possibly Y-intermediates).

ANy help is much appreciated -